# jqgrid summary row is not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to add a summary row to my grid.
but smmary row doesn't work on my grid.
I can see the summary row but there are no numeric data.
please tell me how to resolve it
thanks.

```
$("#salesList").jqGrid({
                datatype: "json",
                jsonReader: {
                    root: "rows",
                    page: "page",
                    total: "total",
                    records: "records",
                    repeatitems: false,
                    id: "0"
                },
                url: "/SalesReport/GetDetailedSalesList?startDate=" + $("#txtStartDate").val() + "&endDate=" + $("#txtEndDate").val(),
                loadtext: "Loading...",
                colNames: [
                    'Date',
                    'Name',
                    'Price',
                    'Tax'
                ],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'reg_date', width: 100, formatter: getTime },
                    { name: 'name', width: 80 },
                    { name: 'PRICE', index: 'PRICE', width: 80, align: "right", formatter: 'number', formatoptions: { decimalPlaces: 2} },
                    { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 80, align: "right", formatter: 'number', formatoptions: { decimalPlaces: 2} }
                ],
                height: 450,
                rowNum: 10,
                sortname: 'reg_date',
                viewrecords: true,
                autowidth: true,
                shrinkToFit: false,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                pager: '#pager1',
                footerrow: true,
                userDataOnFooter: true,
                rownumbers: true,
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be problem try changing

`$("#txtStartDate").val()` to `$("#txtStartDate").text()`

And

`$("#txtEndDate").val()` to `$("#txtEndDate").text()`

Comment: Thanks. but it's not a problem with general data in row. It's good working with display general data in normal row. I'm just talking about only about summary row.